# Zappa AWS staticfiles issue

Tags: python, django, aws-lambda, zappa

When deploying a Django (v3.0.3) project to AWS Lambda using Zappa, I get an error that the package django.contrib.staticfiles could not be found.

This looks strange as this package is part of the Django core apps and the project runs on the local development server with no issues whatsoever. My app listing looks as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    # 3rd party apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_extensions',
    'mapwidgets',
    'crispy_forms',
    'attachments',
    'leaflet',
    'django_tables2',
    'django_filters',
    'zappa_django_utils',
    'django_s3_storage',
    # Project apps
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'
]
```

Cloudwatch gives me the following error log. Have been trying various solutions (reinstalling environment, redeploying Lambda function, ...). Nothing works and this is slowly driving me nuts ;-). The Lambda function managed to run before and I have no idea what I changed to break it. I can confirm that the necessary permissions to access static files in the designated S3 bucket are available and working. Any ideas on what's happening from the community?

```
[ERROR] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.staticfiles'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 609, in lambda_handler
    return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 240, in lambda_handler
    handler = cls()
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 146, in __init__
    wsgi_app_function = get_django_wsgi(self.settings.DJANGO_SETTINGS)
  File "/var/task/zappa/ext/django_zappa.py", line 20, in get_django_wsgi
    return get_wsgi_application()
  File "/var/task/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/var/task/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/var/task/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/var/task/django/apps/config.py", line 136, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

Comment: Still having this issue? Post your `zappa_settings.json`. Are you 10000% sure it is downloading what it needs from S3? Is `slim_handler` true in your settings?

Comment: Never actually figured out what happened, started with a fresh setup and it all worked. I'm trying to avoid the ``slim_handler`` option as it has generated problems for me in the past.

Comment: I found this while looking for problems with `slim_handler: true`, my issue ended up being a combo of S3 permissions and slim_handler problems with Windows. Fixing S3 permissions then starting fresh in a Linux environment solved my issue as well.